# Saying table doesn't exist PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have an issue, after I imported my data and I tried the select command it says table doesn't exist, what can I do? to solve this.

```sql
SELECT years , profit 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE  table_name = 'brew'
and years in(2019,2018,2017)
group by years
```

Comment: Are you sure you imported the data correctly? You could attach the import form you used.

Comment: Please show us how exactly you "imported your data" and what the exact error message is. Also, as most of the current answers remark, your query seems to be faulty - it's unclear what you expect it to do, for there are no columns `years` and `profit` in [`information_schema.tables`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-tables.html)

Comment: Lets simplify your query: `SELECT * FROM information_schema.tables WHERE  table_name = 'brew';` Do you see any columns named `years` or `profit` in the result? Did you get any results at all?

Comment: That information schema I added was from here I saw it, this your source code just brought out the column headers of the schema

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you meant to query `brew`, not `information_schema.tables`, which is part of PosgreSQL's data dictionary:

```sql
SELECT   years, SUM(profit)
FROM     brew
WHERE    years IN (2019, 2018, 2017)
GROUP BY years
```

Comment: The issue is not the source codes, I have imported the CSV file and I have done everything but it keeps on saying the table doesn't exist. You know where importing, you can choose to write codes or choose to input the column name and the data type, I did everything but It's still saying table doesn't exisyt. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Information_schema.tables is a view that provides information about the tables in the database, you don't use it to retrieve data from tables. Also as you're grouping by years you need an aggregate function for profit, I'm assuming you want the total.

Try:

```sql
SELECT years , sum(profit) FROM brew WHERE years in(2019,2018,2017)
group by years
```

Comment: The issue is not the source codes, I have imported the CSV file and I have done everything but it keeps on saying the table doesn't exist. You know where importing, you can choose to write codes or choose to input the column name and the data type, I did everything but It's still saying table doesn't exist. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the query today you are running that says "table does not exist"?  It cannot be the one you posted, as the view information_schema.tables will exist.

Answer (score 0):

The FROM clause is where you put which table you want, the WHERE clause is where you specify constraints.

Comment: The issue is not the source codes, I have imported the CSV file and I have done everything but it keeps on saying the table doesn't exist. You know where importing, you can choose to write codes or choose to input the column name and the data type, I did everything but It's still saying table doesn't exisyt. What am I missing?